# How to write a Windows service with .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net

Currently we have a simple windows service that runs a scheduled job every 5 minutes. the job (located in a simple .cs file) just runs a query against a database tables and sends out an email. Simple.

I would like to add .NET Core to the service to take advantage of the new features. Or, start from scratch. either way, I cannot find a simple example of a windows service (or scheduled task etc) that can run with .NET Core.

My target is windows server, so, I want to run the full framework. Everything I see references ASP.NET core etc. I do not need anything like self hosting/web api.

UPDATE:
So my original question was marked as duplicate, however I do not feel that it is.  Perhaps I need to expand on the complexity a little.

We "home wrote" a background task scheduler. it performs 3 tasks

1) Every 10 seconds, look in a particular directory and move files from that temp directory to Azure Blob storage.

2) Every 10 seconds check a database table and fire off a web api call with an ID of a job. (The endpoint does "some work" independent of the windows service)

3) Every 8 hours process files inside a different directory, perform some "logic" and remove the files.

Another part of the application is deployed as Worker Roles in Azure. This piece has 6 seperate scheduled tasks that run at various intervals as well. I would like to port both of them.

While porting the other WEB applications to Asp.NET Core, I realized this piece could benefit from some of the new features in Core. (JSON configurations, Services, ect).  I have yet to find a simple working example of this.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService ?

Comment: Like most things people try to write as services, **this should not be implemented as a service.** It should be a simple Windows application that does not display an UI and therefore runs in the background. Set up a Scheduled Task that runs the EXE at the desired time interval.

Comment: @Cody. My explanation was a little too simple. I have expanded on it.

Comment: If it is not a duplicate, then what are you asking apart from the question in the title? I don't see any other question than that.

Comment: @Bent. Perhaps I am not asking the question in the proper way. I am open to an entire re-design of the process. I simply cannot find a good starting point to writing a simple task scheduler that can take advantage of all the .NET Core has to offer.

Comment: You can create a .NET core console app that runs in the background. Publish it as an exe which is kicked off by a windows service.
Check this out: https://www.bayological.io/Post/How-to-create-a-self-contained-long-running-NET-Core-console-app